# Algoritmo MacKay Neal - Rellenado de una matriz con unos y ceros

Tags: algoritmos, matlab, matrices

Necesito rellenar una matriz con unos y ceros. Los parámetros que se proporcionan son su dimensión (N columnas y k=N*(1-r) filas) y dos vectores h y v que representan la distribución de filas y columnas, respectivamente. Por ejemplo supongamos que tenemos una matriz de dimensión 5x10, cuyos vectores h y v toman los siguientes valores:

```
v = [0 0.2 0 0.4 0.4];
h = [0 0.1 0.2 0 0.1 0.3 0 0 0.2 0.1];
```

Ello significa que tenemos la siguiente información sobre las filas de H:

- Un 10% del total contiene 2 unos (y el resto de sus elementos son ceros).
- Un 10% del total contiene 5 unos (y el resto de sus elementos son ceros).
- Un 10% del total contiene 10 unos.
- Un 20% del total contiene 3 unos (y el resto de sus elementos son ceros).
- Un 20% del total contiene 9 unos (y el resto de sus elementos -en este caso, uno- son ceros).
- Un 30% del total contiene 6 unos (y el resto de sus elementos son ceros).
- Ninguna de sus filas tiene un solo, o 4, o 7, u 8, (o ningún) uno.

Y, en cuanto a las columnas de H:

- Un 20% del total de las mismas contiene 2 unos (y el resto de sus elementos son ceros).
- Un 40% del total de las mismas contiene 4 unos (y el resto de sus elementos -en este caso, uno- son ceros).
- Un 40% del total de las mismas contiene 5 unos.
- Ninguna de sus columnas tiene un solo, o 3, (o ningún) uno.

Bajo estas premisas, he utilizado el siguiente código:

```
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
% MacKayNeal Function                                                     %
%                                                                         %
% Inputs                                                                  %
% N: length of the codeword (Number of columns of parity-check matrix H)  %
% r: rate of the LDPC code                                                %
% v: distribution of edges                                                %
% h: distribution of nodes                                                %
%                                                                         %
% Outputs                                                                 %
% H: parity-check matrix                                                  %
%                                                                         %
% Author: Aitor López Hernández                                           %
%                                                                         %
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %

function H = MacKayNeal(N,r,v,h)

H = zeros(N*(1-r),N); % Creation of an idle parity-check matrix

a = []; % Number of 1s per column of H
for i=1:length(v)
    for j=1:(v(i)*N)
        a = [a,i];
    end
end

b = []; % Number of 1s per row of H
for i=1:length(h)
    for j=1:(h(i)*(N*(1-r)))
        b = [b,i];
    end
end

b_i = 1:length(b); % Indexes of rows of H that still have 1s to append

for i=1:N
    for j=1:1:length(b)
    if b(j) == 0
        b_i = setdiff(b_i,b(j));
    end
    end
    c = datasample(b_i,a(i),'Replace',false);
    c_i = zeros(1,length(b));
    for j=1:a(i) 
        H(c(j),i)=1;
        c_i(1,c(j))=1;
    end
    b = b - c_i;
end

% Removal of length-4 cycles

for i=1:N*(1-r)-1
    for j=i+1:N*(1-r)
        w = and(H(i,:),H(j,:));
        c1 = find(w);
        lc = length(c1);
        if lc > 1
            % If found, flip one 1 to 0 in the row with less number of 1s
            if length(find(H(i,:))) < length(find(H(j,:)))
            % Repeat the process until only one column left
            for cc = 1:(lc-1)
                 H(j,c1(cc)) = 0;
            end
            else
            for cc = 1:(lc-1)
                H(i,c1(cc)) = 0;
            end
            end
        end
    end
end
end
```

(La parte a continuación del comentario "Removal of 4-length cycles" no es relevante para mi consulta).

El problema reside en las multiplicaciones que aparecen en los bucles en las líneas 5 y 11. Sus resultados han de ser necesariamente enteros para que el algoritmo funcione (manteniendo la suma de los elementos de v y h igual a 1, ya que sus elementos representan distribuciones de probabilidad).

Se pueden utilizar como ejemplo los siguientes valores para mostrar el mal funcionamiento de mi código. Aunque el programa se ejecuta sin errores, se observa que no lo hace adecuadamente, ya que el vector b no tiene un tamaño de N(1-r) = 50 sino de 48 elementos.

```
N = 100;
r = 0.5;
h = [0 0.17 0.03 0.2 0 0 0.17 0.3 0 0 0 0 0.03 0.1];
v = [0 0.1 0 0 0 0.7 0.2];
```

Este algoritmo necesita funcionar para valores mucho mayores que N=100 y otros factores distintos a r=0.5 -y lo mismo aplica a v y h, los cuales también podrían tener valores con muchos más decimales (ya que se obtienen como resultado de un problema de optimización con la función 'fmincon').

¿Alguien tiene alguna solución para mi problema?

Muchas gracias de antemano, y un saludo.